# Google App Engine Django BooleanProperty not binding to table

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have the following,

```
class Company(db.Model):
    companyvalid = db.BooleanProperty(required=True)

class AddCompanyForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = Company
        exclude = ['companyentrytime']
        exclude = ['companylatlong']
```

however I cannot get the o/p from the Django stored in the database. I can also only add a record when the checkbox is checked, but this is not reflected in the underlying table when saving the record. What is the smartest way to do this? Thanks

```
class AddCompanyCategoriesHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        memcache.flush_all()
        form_requirements = AddCompanyCategoriesForm()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'addcompanycat.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {'form': form_requirements}))

def post(self):
        form_requirements = AddCompanyCategoriesForm(data=self.request.POST)
        if form_requirements.is_valid():
                myname = form_requirements.clean_data['categoryname']
                entity = form_requirements.save(commit=False)   
                entity.put()
```

=========================================================================================

I'm trying to use the BooleanField, but this fails to work, with the server giving out a 504 error. Here is my model. I've been experimenting with this BooleanFields format, but I'm not sure how this relates to my model. My model is

```
class Company(db.Model):
    companyurl = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    companyname = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    companydesc = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    companyaddress = db.PostalAddressProperty(required=True)
    companypostcode = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    companyemail = db.EmailProperty(required=True)
    companycountry = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    companyvalid = db.BooleanProperty()
    #companyvalid = db.BooleanField(required=True, label="Check this")
    companyentrytime = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    companylatlong = db.GeoPtProperty()
    @property
    def catname(self):
        return self.companycategory.name
    companycategory = db.ReferenceProperty(CompanyCategory, collection_name='compcategory')
```

and the following

```
class AddCompanyForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        #companyvalid = model.BooleanField(default=False)
        exclude = ['companyentrytime']
        exclude = ['companylatlong']
```

So my question is that if I have to use this BooleanField, how should I put it in the AddCompanyForm and should there be an entry in the model?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, odd why formatting was awry. Fixed now, but checkbox is not :-(

Comment: Sorry, this indentation is still not valid. If you're not getting syntax errors, then the relevant bits of code aren't actually running.

Comment: It's fine in the code, its copying it here that it fails. Its odd.

Comment: You're not going to get many answers with obviously incorrect indentation - please spend the time to fix if you really want an answer. why are you using `BooleanProperty` rather than `BooleanField`? What do you mean by "cannot get the o/p from the Django stored in the database"?   What do you mean by "I can also only add a record when the checkbox is checked, but this is not reflected in the underlying table when saving the record" - unclear - you can only save when the checkbox is checked but...? but the field that corresponds to the checkbox does not get set?

Comment: @scytale The formatting between copying and pasting from my work file to here is still not working well. There are no indentation error or syntax errors in my code due indentation. And despite getting the checkbox rendering along with all over properties, when the entity is saved, the checkbox status never ends up in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using BooleanField (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield)  rather than Boolean Property in your model?

Comment: I have updated my question. I have tried the BooleanField, but how does this fit in with the model?

Comment: is your model a subclass of django.db.models.Model?